# XAMPP localhost error not found

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

First I tried to start apache but got unexpected error because default port 80 is being used by another program then I tried to terminate that program with in windows command line I typed `resmon.exe` to find out which program is using the port 80. I found out it is `PID 4`  then I tried to terminate with command `taskkill/ PID 4` but got this

> "ERROR: The process with PID 4 could not be terminated.
>
> Reason: Access
> is denied.

Secondly, I tried to change ports after and get apache running but got another problem

> HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

It is meaning local host could not be found. I got stuck now any ideas?

Comment: First of all, try to run `CMD` as administrator. Second, Do you have **skype**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be skype or windows IIS server running on your port 80

try this

1. Run cmd as Administrator
2. use `C:\>Taskkill /PID 'pid of your process' /F`  to kill the task